# Class structure that change without violating SOLID principle

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

This is my first question here so let me know if additional info is required...

I am new to designing so my knowledge is a little limited, so I have this application in which I have a project class, the project goes through 7 stages, and those stages have nothing in common...first one is Discovery, which contains question about the requirements, second is Product Mapping, which lets the user select products required by the project...

The problem comes, that stages keep on getting added or removed...

So I cant put their reference in the class, cuz then I need to modify the class every time. So how to design the flow?

Should I pass the project object into stage object? Then how to keep track on which stage the project is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go for **Process Manager Pattern**.

Each of your stages should be separate class implementing a common Interface/Abstract class(according to your need) and then you need to have a Controller class which will control the work flow of your project. You can add or remove your steps to this Controller class instance as per your requirement.

Comment: Fowler says that [Process Manager](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ProcessManager.html) is an extensive topic.  Is that really appropriate for someone just starting out in design?

Answer (score 0):

You can track the "status" of the Project as `Project.status`, being an `enum` that advances through the appropriate stages. (This assumes that each stage exists only once; it can be re-executed, but would update/ overwrite the previous results.)

Data captured at each stage can be implemented as properties in the Project class (most simple), or (more advanced) "pushed down" into composite entities per-stage.

Don't forget also to take advantage of entities/objects to hold information like Requirement, Product Mapping etc!

Comment: I didnt get what you mean by data captured can be implemented as properties in the Project classes...each stage itself contains object and some buisiness logic...and if i define the properties in the Project class , then i have to add/remove them whenever a stage is added or removed

Comment: As I said, properties in Project assume that stages are permanently defined & occur once (with possible re-execution, updating the values). "Stages added and removed" you say? Perhaps you should be **absolutely crystal clear** with your question & requirements, if you're hoping to get any kind of successful design.

Comment: Stages cannot be permanently defined in my Project class because they change...this is the problem...currently there are 7 stages required...after a week 1 more maybe added..

Comment: You're not clear whether Stages changing are due to 1) _system/customer configuration change_, 2) _requirements discovery or design evolution_, 3) _normal execution flow -- progress of the Project thru it's normal lifecycle_, or 4) _exception/ unusual execution flow -- loops/retries/exception paths/ non-usual flows of Project execution_. Voting -1 due to continued lack of clarity. Since you don't know what you're doing, this project is unlikely to be a success.

Comment: That was due to customer requirement bdw...

Comment: Customer requirement **on what timescale?** Software release, requirements change, twice-yearly configuration change, normal execution, abnormal execution? Good design requires clarity, the only thing that's clear here is that you're not providing that. _I'm afraid I feel frustrated & that I and you are wasting my time with this question. Almost a month after you first posted, you've still failed to clearly define the "variability" you mention which is key to the design. I no longer wish to be involved._